# C# Winform label disabled when switching to another form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm new to Visual Studio & C#, still trying to learn.

I have two forms Form 1 and 2

Click on a label in form 1 will go to form 2.

```
    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        linkLabel1.LinkBehavior = System.Windows.Forms.LinkBehavior.NeverUnderline;

        (new Form2()).Show(); this.Hide();
    }
```

However for form 2, the color of the label text changes to light grey text even though the ForeColor properties is black.

Am i missing out something here? Thank you.

Update: Seems like the text in form 2 appears but it is disabled (greyed out). Is there a way to enable the label? Not sure why is it even disabled in the first place.

Comment: Which label's color is changed to Grey? `linkLabel1` ? or the label on `Form2`?

Comment: I just wrote a piece of code exactly the same as yours and no issue like what you mentioned happened. Could you please explain a little more?

Comment: Got a screenshot?

Comment: All the labels in Form2 changed to Grey. Let me try to see if i can upload a picture here. There are some data loss prevention policies in our organization.

Comment: Side note, it's possible (and you ought to) rename controls and forms after you add them; change the (Name) line in the property grid after you add the control/rename the file. There is nothing more tedious than looking through someone's code where the variables are all meaningless names button26, linklabel9..it's harder for us to understand and harder for you to code because you have to remember a ton of unnecessary info. Your name is Jayy, not human105294762528; your Form2 should be called eg EditAddressForm and your link label should be called eg openAddressEditorLinkLabel

Comment: Sorry guys, can't seem to upload a pic. But i think the issue is that all the text/labels are greyed out 

The greyed out part looks something like the answer in this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42856525/ms-access-why-does-label-formatting-change-when-textbox-is-disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve my issue.

Error msg: forms that are not enabled cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box

The form was not enabled, so i had to enable it

```
oneDriveForm.Enabled = true;
```

Full code below

```
    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        linkLabel1.LinkBehavior = System.Windows.Forms.LinkBehavior.NeverUnderline;

        SubOneDriveForm oneDriveForm = new SubOneDriveForm();
        oneDriveForm.Enabled = true;

        oneDriveForm.ShowDialog();

        }
```

Reference:
[Button enabling not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729928/button-enabling-not-working-correctly)

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.